# Check existence of an E-mail Address

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am developing a client email sender program by Java.

> Now I am developing a class that can check that an email address is actually available or not. There is a way to check the domain part of the email address(by *MX Record checking*). But I can't found a way to check the existence of the local part of an email address.

If I want to check a local part of an email address of gmail account is actually exists or not that means - *'localpart@gmail.com'* here *'localpart'* is my input.

Is it possible to check the existence of that email address?

Comment: No, it isn't. Spammers would love this feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check mail address is exists or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514005/how-to-check-mail-address-is-exists-or-not)

Comment: You can send e verification email and look for error reply from server

Comment: @Maxx Unless the service provider doesn't return errors for nonexistant addresses

Comment: Have a look at here on how to check if the mail bounced back (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150183/send-e-mail-and-check-status) but, as JonK says, the server might not answer back with an error so you'll have to think something else too

Comment: As others have said, the simple answer is no, there's no way to do this.  The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#legaladdress) has some more information.  There may be ways to address this issue if we understand why it is you want to verify that the address is valid.